# Best option for C / Ruby interfacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, interface

I've got a Ruby on Rails application, which needs to communicate with a backend C application, and I'm wondering what the consensus is for the best approach is to this.

The two applications will run on separate servers, with the Rails application on a (partially) public web address.  The C application is entirely within a firewall.  For security reasons, I don't want them sharing a database.  My initial approach is that web services is the right way to go.

Firstly, am I missing any potentially better alternatives to my web services assumption?

Secondly, while I've got plenty of experience using SOAP from C with gSOAP (and importantly, so does the person who will be writing the C-side!), Ruby on Rails prefers the REST model.

But what exactly does a RESTful interface from C code entail?  Is there anything like gSOAP that does RESTFUL interfaces from C?

Does anyone have a feeling which is the path of least resistance here?

EDIT: forgot to mention that the C application does already have a web interface using Aapche / CGI.

Comment: Does the backend C application have a HTTP interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C calling Rails, libcurl is probably not too bad an option. Making REST calls is pretty simple, since it's mostly url via string concatenation plus form-encoding. Examples are abundant:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

If you need Rails to C via REST ... ugh. Perhaps Apache and straight cgi? Or just wrap it in it's own rails app and do the calls directly from that app? Seriously, If you need Rails to C via REST, I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Sounds like a good start, I know we've got a couple of people who've used libcurl before.  The C side won't be a problem.  It already has a web interface, done as you say with Apache / CGI.

Comment: Oh, and since I'm an idiot that forgot that http servers tend to send RESPONSES when you make requests, check out this stack overflow question on how to handle the responses in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395207/how-to-parse-http-responses-in-c (not actually that helpful)

Comment: How are your responses to the C guy going to look? If you output html that can be parsed by libxml, then libcurl + libxml2 might be sufficient. However, I've had some problems with web pages that render correctly that don't seem to parse entirely cleanly with libxml2. That seems controllable (at your end), though.

Comment: I think not too much needs including in the response - pretty much a return code and an error string to go into the logs in case of a failure.  The messaging should be fairly simple create/delete requests for resources, which further convinces me that REST is the way forwards.

Comment: Thankyou.  I have just done a proof of concept program in C that sends a request using libcurl to create an entity in the portal.  Looks like this should all work OK.