# start printing after a empty line in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

let say we have this pointer  called text it print this thing in this format:

```
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 11:42:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2
PHP/5.3.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Content-Length: 12
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
         <--- empty line
```

Start printing this

How can you start printing something when you detect a empty line in c or c++?

Comment: You need to explain your problem better.  A "pointer" doesn't print.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: @user1341993 - Please give yourself a username - easier to identify people. Does not need to be your real name.

Comment: as usual this kind of OP want a code and flee once he gets it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read line by line, just check the length of the line. If the length is zero, then you have an empty line.

If you have to check a memory buffer, then have a counter that is reset to zero on newline. If you reach a newline and the counter already is zero, then you have an empty line.

**Edit:** Some code how to do this with a memory buffer:

```
char *buffer = "Hello\nWorld\n\nFoo\n";
char *data_start = NULL;

char *line_beg, *p;
for (line_beg = p = buffer; *p; p++)
{
    if (*p == '\n')
    {
        if (line_beg == p)
        {
            /* Empty line */
            data_start = p + 1;
            break;
        }
        line_beg = p + 1;
    }
}

if (data_start != NULL)
    printf("Data: %s", data_start);
```

Comment: any example Joachim ? in code

Comment: if( ::strlen( pointer ) == 0 ) //print stuff

Answer (score 0):

As this is a continuation of a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244569/send-http-post-request-to-php-code-in-c-or-c), I think you may wish to explore [fdopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html)
. It will be an easier way of reading the output line by line with [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html). You can then easily identify blank lines,