# Inputting variable into website

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a giveaway happening involving codes that need to be entered, and I wanted to make a program that would generate codes that could be entered, and then put them into the online form.

1) First off, I have already created the generator using C++, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient language for generating these types of things, and algorithms in general, but this is not as important.

2) The main part that I was wondering about was if (and how) there was a way that I could take all these codes and then input them online, without doing the manual work of copy-pasting.

Comment: 1) C++ is in general a very efficient language. Anyway, your bottleneck is most probably given by the 2nd part, so it doesn't really matter 2) Sure, you can write a program that simulates the behaviour of a web browser. However, most likely this will fail: the server will detect that all these attempts are automated (because they all come from the same IP, because they come too fast...) and reject them. This would be a defense against fraud, and also against a possible Denial of Service attack. So you are probably wasting your time.

Comment: Thank you lots! Not that I am going to go through with it, but how would I set up the program to simulate the web browser?

Comment: You certainly don't write it from scratch, you need to find a library that supports it. I can't help you much here, because I'm not working on web technologies. I think boost/asio could be a starting point, but be careful - this suggestion could be completely wrong. Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HTTP Request in C++ and directly send it to the server.
To do so:

1. Figure out what the HTML form does (there's a Firefox Plugin called "Firebug" which shows all the Requests done by a Site). If you'r lucky, the form is simple calling a PHP script via a HTTP GET or POST Request.
2. Build the Request in your C++ Code (have a look at this: [Send Http "Post" Request To Php Code in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244569/send-http-post-request-to-php-code-in-c-or-c) if you have to make a POST Request)
3. Send the Request
4. Handle the Answer

Please excuse my bad english ;)